# Username-Password Flow OAuth unable to access web page

Tags: oauth

I can't find any documentation to suggest this would be a limitation, but using my access_token from a usernamepassword flow I can access api endpoints but not a url like instance.salesforce.com/id. Thoughts?

My connected app has web, full etc for access level.

Comment: I ended up getting around this by using making a SOAP request for a session ID. I'm not going to close the question just yet, a oauth token would be better.

Comment: I believe you need to use the front door to use the session token. See [frontdoor.jsp](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/security_frontdoorjsp.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check that profile of the user you are logging in with doesn't have "API only User" tickbox checked (located under "Administrative Permissions" section on profile page).

Comment: Nope. The user is my user and a system administrator

Answer (score 0):

Add the URL you are trying to access in remote sites. Remote sites can be accessed from Administration Setup - -> Security Controls -->Remote Site Setting